# in Vue js from one Detail page to master detail page

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I Want to go to another detail page from one detail page.

For example, my current page is `http://localhost:8000/#/product/bridal-suit` where `bridal-suit` is a dynamic slug,

In this page above mentioned related products. On the related products when I click one of them, it should open same page with data changed but the problem is that is not changing and its still same.

This is the code for related products `v-bind:to="'/product/'+ product.slug"`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What are you using for changing/updating data? do you have to call API and pass slug to get specific data?

Comment: yes i am using api, the url is changed but data is not changed, when i am going from home page to product detail page then its working fine, but when from product detail page to product detail page then only url is changed data not.

Answer (score 0):

Add `:key` attribute to your component.

For example if your component looks like this:

```js
<ProductItem />
```

and what you are changing is `$route.params.slug` then add `slug` as the `:key`:

```js
<ProductItem :key="$route.params.slug" />
```

The change of a `slug` will force re-render on your Component and refresh data :-)

So in your case I am guessing that passing `:key="product.slug"` to your component resolve the issue.

Some more reading about [updating components](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/).

Comment: You can also watch the route to check for any changes in route params, as explained in the Vue Router docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes